# Docker Influx DB and Nodejs - Connection Refused

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, influxdb

I have been experimenting with InfluxDB (time series database) and trying to use Docker. From what I've read, I have defined my nodejs app and InfluxDB in a `DockerCompose` file.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:12

# Create working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD "node" "websocket.js"
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: docker-td-node-api
    build: .
    command: "node websocket.js"
    depends_on:
      - "influx-db"
  influx-db:
    image: influxdb
    ports: 
      - "8086:8086"
```

Everything starts up correctly except for when my nodejs app tries to communicate with the docker container (using an InfluxDB nodejs library), it keeps saying:

```
web_1        | Getting database names...
web_1        | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8086
web_1        |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16) {
web_1        |   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
web_1        |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
web_1        |   syscall: 'connect',
web_1        |   address: '127.0.0.1',
web_1        |   port: 8086
web_1        | }
```

I find this odd because from a separate terminal, I can query the database through port 8086 via:

```
$curl -G http://127.0.0.1:8086/query --data-urlencode "q=CREATE DATABASE mydb"
{"results":[{"statement_id":0,"messages":[{"level":"warning","text":"deprecated use of 'CREATE DATABASE mydb' in a read only context, please use a POST request instead"}]}]}
```

When I start up with `docker-compose up` which launches both the nodejs & InfluxDB, I can then launch the nodejs app in a separate terminal window and it connects perfectly through port 8086.

Is there something I'm missing that is preventing the nodejs app in a docker container from communicating to the InfluxDB in another docker container? I was under the impression the `docker-compose` file should establish the networking for it.

Thanks

Comment: `localhost` in Docker is typically "this container"; it's a different `localhost` for each container and a different `localhost` from the host system.  Between containers you can use the Compose block names as host names: try connecting to `influx-db` as a host name.

Comment: What @DavidMaze said is true but you also need to make sure that your DB is up when you are trying to connect to it. You can do it by adding ```healthcheck```  in ```influx-db``` or by polling the DB in your node.js app. I prefer the healthcheck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DavidMaze and @yogeshwar Thank you for your replies! Yep, in my database connection, I changed it to `influx-db` which was what I named my service and it worked like a charm! Thanks for your help!